# Error: No org-babel-initiate-session function for bash!

Tags: org-babel

I would like to use the session feature for bash source blocks, and receive the error message.

```
No org-babel-initiate-session function for bash!
```

A simple code is shown below. The code can be executed through <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>. Yet I received the error message when pressing <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :session *bash*
echo $0
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
|           |
| /bin/bash |
```

Interestingly, <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-v</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> works for `sh` source block.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :session *sh*
echo $0
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
|         |
| /bin/sh |
```

I use [doom](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs) emacs, and the vanilla configuration for both org-mode and org-babel. Anyone knows what the potential issues are.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for asking this question!! I didn't know about `C-c C-v z`, cool!!

Answer (score 1):

> I think you uncovered a bug or something fell through the cracks when `ob-shell.el` was built.
>   *Please submit bug report to org-mode repo.*

### Below is a temporary workaround

1. Execute the *missing* `org-babel-bash-initiate-session` function definition below:

```
(defun org-babel-bash-initiate-session (&optional session _params)
  "Initiate a session named SESSION according to PARAMS."
  (when (and session (not (string= session "none")))
    (save-window-excursion
      (or (org-babel-comint-buffer-livep session)
          (progn
        (shell session)
        ;; Needed for Emacs 23 since the marker is initially
        ;; undefined and the filter functions try to use it without
        ;; checking.
        (set-marker comint-last-output-start (point))
        (get-buffer (current-buffer)))))))
```

> **Note:** I just copied `org-babel-sh-initiate-session` definition from [ob-shell.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/c996fe1ec69de0082043397d4965d08cb94892fb/lisp/org/ob-shell.el#L187) and changed `-sh-` to `-bash-`.

2. Execute bash `SRC` again with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>.
3. Use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-v</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd>.

Thank you for asking your question!

---

> **The answer code was tested using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   org version: 9.1.2

Answer (score 0):

As another option, I usually list `bash` for my "shell script" source blocks, I am simply aliasing the initiate session function from sh:

```
(defun org-babel-bash-initiate-session (&optional session _params)
  "Initiate a bash/sh session named SESSION according to PARAMS."
  (org-babel-sh-initiate-session session _params))
```